# How do I get a UITableViewCell in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, powerschool

I would like to replicate the design of the powerschool app  as it seems there is a cell inside a cell. How do I do this?

[image: Example cell]

Comment: What makes you think that's a cell in a cell?

Comment: it kind of looks like it. I don't really know what it is.

Comment: It looks like a custom cell with a number of subviews...

Comment: Really, don't do that :) just customize your cell with subviews

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

Try instead to make a custom TableViewCell with all the subviews to satisfy your design needs.

Comment: Why not do that? Sometimes it's highly useful to include a cell inside another cell. I bet Facebook has something like that for shared posts: the shared post is just a post cell inside another post cell. If you manage to simply include, you don't have to maintain 2 separate cells which are the same, just one inside the other. If you make 2 separate cells you'll have to update them both for each little change you decide to do on it.